# Does document.open() create a whole new document or just erase what was already there?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a whole new document with Javascript to then write to, and I can't seem to grasp whether

```
document.open() 
document.write()
document.close()
```

will create a whole new document, or just rewrite what is already there?

What is the most common/simple way to open a new document to write to with Javascript?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would "opening a new document" look like exactly? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: @deceze I'd like to write the output of an array into a new document using document.write() - just can't figure out how to make a new document with Javascript

Comment: How do you think "a new document" would behave? Would it open a new window? A file on disk? A frame inside the current document? Purely something in memory that's not visible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open

document.open();

If a document exists in the target, **this method clears it**

Also, an automatic document.open() call happens when document.write() is called after the page has loaded, but that's not defined in the W3C specification.

**Do not confuse this method with window.open(). document.open allows you to overwrite the current document or append to it**, while window.open provides a way to open a new window, leaving the current document intact. Since window is the global object, just calling open(...) does the same as window.open(...).You can close the opened document using document.close().

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really clears things up. How would I choose between overwriting the current document or appending to it with document.open()?

Comment: to overwrite the whole document, I would recommend using window.open, with the target set to _self. This will create a new instance - so any instance vars that are still stored in the browser during that session, will not cause conflicts since you are creating a brand new environment and context.